# Why junit ComparisonFailure is not used by assertEquals(Object, Object)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

In Junit 4, do you see any drawback to throw a `ComparisonFailure` instead of an `AssertionError` when assertEquals(Object, Object) fails ?

assertEquals(Object, Object) throws

- a `ComparisonFailure` if both expected and actual are String
- an `AssertionError` if either is not a String

`AssertionError` message is already of the form

```
"expected:<"+ expected.toString() +"> but was <"+ actual.toString()
```

(via `String.valueOf`, see below junit-4.8.2 method invoked by Assert.assertEquals(Object, Object) to build AssertionError message):

```
static String format(Object expected, Object actual) {
    ...
    String expectedString= String.valueOf(expected);
    String actualString=   String.valueOf(actual);
    ...
    return formatted+"expected:<"+ expectedString +"> but was:<"+ actualString +">";
```

`ComparisonFailure` provide far more readable way to spot the differences in dialog box of eclipse or [Intellij IDEA](http://piotrjagielski.com/blog/a-cool-technique-for-object-comparison-in-junit/) (FEST-Assert throws this exception)

[Update: question edited to focus on ComparisonFailure/AssertionError discussion.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We started with comparing strings because it was obvious how to make the error message more helpful. We never expanded ComparisonFailure to general objects because it wasn't clear how to do so in a general way. As other have suggested, you're welcome to add special assertions if you can provide better error messages or move to Hamcrest, which provides a general mechanism for adding useful failure messages.

Regards,

Kent

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Hamcrest, I've never heard of it before. Looks interesting. http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/

Answer (score 2):

I think you can certainly write your own substitute assertEquals method to do that without any significant problems, if that works for you.

However, in the general case (from the point of view of the framework developers), is it a good idea, I'm not sure. Often the failure objects won't have a toString implmentation, at which point the failure message from the IDE will be very misleading. You would get the impression that the comparison was on reference identity, when it may not have been.

In other words, it is valuable if the objects have a meaningful toString implementation, otherwise it may not be.

Comment: I agree it is more valuable when objects have a meaningful toString().

Comment: Otherwise the current message is already giving the impression that the comparison was on reference identity : "java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<...@c2f1> but was:<...@20ba>"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with current JUnit implementation, with two exception classes. Mostly because it gives us an ability to differentiate comparison problems (`ComparisonFailure`) and more "severe" type incompatibility problems (`AssertionError`).

In general, text message inside an `Exception` is just a helper for a human being, and is not meant to be touched by any software tools. That's why type of thrown exception is **the only** indicator of the problem happened.

Comment: In current junit it's not possible to differentiate between *non-string* comparison problems and incompatibility problems : both raise *AssertionError*. ComparisonFailure is raised only for String comparisons.