# Why do we need org.junit.ComparisonFailure?

Tags: java, junit

Why does separate `AssertionError` subclass `org.junit.ComparisonFailure` exists? Is the `org.junit.AssertioError` not enough for `assertEquals(String, String)`?

Answer (score 0):

[Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571052/why-junit-comparisonfailure-is-not-used-by-assertequalsobject-object) may have the answer you're looking for:

> We started with comparing strings because it was obvious how to make
>   the error message more helpful. We never expanded ComparisonFailure to
>   general objects because it wasn't clear how to do so in a general way.
>   As other have suggested, you're welcome to add special assertions if
>   you can provide better error messages or move to Hamcrest, which
>   provides a general mechanism for adding useful failure messages.